# Manually order intersections UpSetR

Tags: r, upsetr

I'm trying to manually order my intersections with `UpSetR` but I don't know if it's possible to do it. `order.by` only allows `freq` or `degree` and I don't see any other parameter that could produce what I want.

```
a <- list(one = c(1, 2, 3, 5,11,19), 
          two = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 11, 13), 
          three = c(1, 5, 6, 7, 11, 19),
          four = c(1, 5, 6, 8, 13, 19))
upset(fromList(a), sets = c("one", "two", "three", "four"))
```

On the left is what I actually have, on the right is what I want to reproduce.
[image]

Does anyone knows if it is possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution with `ComplexUpset` package :

```
 if(!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("krassowski/complex-upset") 


upset(a,colnames(a),intersections=list(c("one"),c("one","two"),c("one","two","three","four"),c("one","three","four"),c("one","two","three"),c("three"),c("two"),c("four"),c("three","four"),c("two","four")),sort_intersections=FALSE)
```